Siesta-grid generation time
Dear Siesta Users/Developers
I use siesta with ASE to do a NEB job. In a NEB calculation, many image files are generated and each one should be converged. The most of time for my calculation is devoted to the grid generation (almost 50 sec for my HP server with 20 CPU, compared to 5 sec for each SCF step). I use mesh cutoff of 200Ry. My reaction is on the surface of a doped graphene with ~15A vacuum in z direction.
Is there any method to increase grid generation speed? For example, the code uses the previous information or other techniques.
thanks
reza

+1. Welcome to our community.
